# Error parsing the query token line error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to enter fictional values into a table I created with columns. I am getting this error:

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501

```
insert into employees (`first`, `last`, `title`, `age`, `salary`)
values (`Jonie`, `Weber`, `Secretary`, `28`, `19500`))
```

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 2,Token in error = ` ]

I have entered:

```
insert into employees (`first`, `last`, `title`, `age`, `salary`)
values (`Jonie`, `Weber`, `Secretary`, `28`, `19500`));
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around strings, not backticks:

```
insert into employees (first, last, title, age, salary) 
values ('Jonie', 'Weber', 'Secretary', 28, 19500)
```

And you have a `)` too much at the end.